# Is $f(f^{-1}(B))$ a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a Borel measurable function, i.e. $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set for any Borel set $B$.

> For any Borel set $B\subset \Bbb R$, is it true that $f(f^{-1}(B))$ is a Borel set?

I know that even a continuous image of a Borel set need not be Borel, i.e. $f(A)$ need not be Borel for a Borel set $A$. However, does anything change if $A$ has a very special form of $A=f^{-1}(B)$?

I have a feeling that $f(f^{-1}(B))$ need not be a Borel set but I can't think of a good counterexample yet.

Comment: Recall that $f(f^{-1}(B))=B \cap f(\mathbb{R})$. So you really need to consider the case $B=\mathbb{R}$ ie find if the image of a Borel measurable function must be Borel.

Comment: @Mindlack: And this is not true in general. Pick any $g$ Borel measurable and $C$ Borel such that $g(C)$ is not Borel, and consider $f(x) = g(x) 1_C (x)$. Then $g(C) \subset f(\Bbb{R}) \subset g(C) \cup \{0\}$, so that the image of $f$ is note Borel measurable.

Comment: @PhoemueX Your comment should have been an answer in my opinion